# My eCPM (RPM) are low since migration to new AdMob version

Tags: android, admob, ads

Few days ago, I have migrated my AdMob account to the new version. Since then, some eCPM (RPM) are lower than the previous version!

Example : one on my app had previously 0.10$ (which is already low), but now, it's about 0.01$!

Oh, and this app is **french only**, maybe that was a problem and explain why I have such lower eCPM?

What can I do? How can increase my eCPM for the current language? With interstitial ads (but I hate them)? Or it takes times to the new AdMob properly calculate the effective CPM?

Any advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always ad revenue has taken a dive since 1-Jul

It will pick up again. Best way to insulate yourself against low RPM for a network is to use mediation.

Comment: Yes. There are lots of ad networks. I'd recommend choosing three that you are comfortable with and integrating them. Then you can find out which is of most value to you.

Comment: I have my favourite networks, but I won't provide as recommendations here. I suggest you look for recent recommendations and stick with those networks that pay reliably (some don't), stick to providing ads within the terms you have stipulated (ie don't shows adult ads when you have asked not to), don't provide uber annoying flashing ads, ads that launch full screen by themselves and definitely no push notification ads.